# Active Record Associations to prevent duplicate database entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, psql

I am setting up a Ruby on Rails application where a User will have an Album collection. My initial thinking was to set it up with a simple User has_many Albums and Albums belongs to Users. The problem that arises here is that the Album table will have duplicates entries, only distinguished by user_id.

```
id  | album_name  | artist_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | user_id 
-----+-------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------
   2 | SuperRando |   3       | 2015-11-13 00:03:51.790759 | 2015-11-13 00:03:51.790759 |  1       
   3 | SuperRando |   3       | 2015-11-13 00:19:08.438907 | 2015-11-13 00:19:08.438907 |  2
```

So what would be the best course of action so I could have an Album table with all unique albums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could model it using a join table:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_albums
  has_many :users, through: :user_albums
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_albums
  has_many :albums, through: :user_albums
end

class UserAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :album
end
```

So, your schema would like somewhat like this:

```
create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "user_albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "album_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now, the way you would call this code in your controller or console. you can do this:

1. Create User: `user = User.create(params)`
2. Find or Create an album: `album = Album.find_or_create_by(params)`
3. Associate user with that album `user.albums << album` & then save it by `user.save`

Now to see user's album. you can do:
`User.take.albums`

to see users of a particular album, you can do 
`Album.take.users`

Hope this answers your question.

For more information have a look at the rails guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association